SpringBoot: Two Datasource Configuration DDL AUTO is not working
I am building a component which connects to two datasources i.e. two MySQL DBs. I am using QueryDSL so I need entity managers for each datasource. For that I have created below config classes.
For Datasource 1
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "a.b.c.d.repository.ds1", entityManagerFactoryRef = "ds1EntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "ds1TransactionManager")
public class DS1DatasourceConfig {

    private Environment environment;

    public DS1DatasourceConfig(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "ds1JpaProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.jpa.ds1")
    JpaProperties ds1JpaProperties() {
        return new JpaProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "ds1DataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.ds1")
    DataSourceProperties ds1DataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "ds1DataSource")
    HikariDataSource ds1DataSource(
            @Qualifier("ds1DataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties ds1DataSourceProperties) {
        return ds1DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "ds1EntityManagerFactory")
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ds1EntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder,
            @Qualifier("ds1DataSource") DataSource dataSource,
            @Qualifier("ds1JpaProperties") JpaProperties jpaProperties) {

        return entityManagerFactoryBuilder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("a.b.c.d.entity.ds1")
                .persistenceUnit("ds1").properties(jpaProperties.getProperties()).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "ds1TransactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager ds1TransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("ds1EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    DataSourceInitializer ds1DataSourceInitializer(@Qualifier("ds1DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();

        String checkScript = environment.getProperty("spring.sql.init.ds1.mode");
        if ("always".compareTo(checkScript) == 0) {
            String fileName = environment.getProperty("spring.sql.init.ds1.filename");
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(fileName)) {
                fileName = "ds1-data.sql";
            }
            ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource(fileName);
            if (classPathResource.exists()) {

                resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(classPathResource);
            }
        }

        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }
}

For Datasource 2
package com.fcc.cp.crs.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "a.b.c.d.repository.ds2", entityManagerFactoryRef = "ds2EntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "ds2TransactionManager")
public class DS2DatasourceConfig {

    private Environment environment;

    public DS2DatasourceConfig(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean(name = "ds2JpaProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.jpa.ds2")
    JpaProperties ds2JpaProperties() {
        return new JpaProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ds2DataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.ds2")
    DataSourceProperties ds2DataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ds2DataSource")
    HikariDataSource ds2DataSource(
            @Qualifier("ds2DataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties ds2DataSourceProperties) {
        return ds2DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ds2EntityManagerFactory")
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ds2EntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder, @Qualifier("ds2DataSource") DataSource dataSource,
            @Qualifier("ds2JpaProperties") JpaProperties jpaProperties) {
        return entityManagerFactoryBuilder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("a.b.c.d.entity.ds2")
                .persistenceUnit("ds2").properties(jpaProperties.getProperties()).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ds2TransactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager ds2TransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("ds2EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    DataSourceInitializer ds2DataSourceInitializer(@Qualifier("ds2DataSource") DataSource dataSource) {

        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        ResourceDatabasePopulator resourceDatabasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();

        String checkScript = environment.getProperty("spring.sql.init.ds2.mode");
        if ("always".compareTo(checkScript) == 0) {
            String fileName = environment.getProperty("spring.sql.init.ds2.filename");
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(fileName)) {
                fileName = "ds2-data.sql";
            }
            ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource(fileName);
            if (classPathResource.exists()) {
                resourceDatabasePopulator.addScript(classPathResource);
            }
        }

        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(resourceDatabasePopulator);
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }
}

application.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    ds1:
      url: jdbc:mysql://${ds1_db_host:localhost}:${ds1_db_port:3306}/${ds1_db_name:ds1}
      username: ${ds1_db_user:user}
      password: ${ds1_db_pass:password}
    ds2:
      url: jdbc:mysql://${ds2_db_host:localhost}:${ds2_db_port:3306}/${ds2_db_name:ds2}
      username: ${ds2_db_user:user}
      password: ${ds2_db_pass:password}
  jpa:
    ds1:
      properties:
        show-sql: ${ds1_show_sql:true}
        hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        hibernate.ddl-auto: ${ds1_ddl_auto:update}
        hibernate.naming.physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    ds2:
      properties:
        show-sql: ${ds2_show_sql:true}
        hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        hibernate.ddl-auto: ${ds2_ddl_auto:update}
        hibernate.naming.physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
  sql:
    init:
      ds1:
        mode: ${ds1_sql_init_mode:never}
      ds2:
        mode: ${ds2_sql_init_mode:never}
  threads:
    virtual:
      enabled: ${virtual_threads:false}

server:
  port: ${port:8085}

When I am starting server, all beans are building successfully and server is starting without any errors but it is not creating tables in db and no sql statement are being printed on console even when show-sql is true.
Also, I checked HikariDataSource don't have a ThreadFactory.
How to solve this?

Why you are having this issue
show-sql (here) and hibernate.ddl-auto (here) are both properties managed by Spring Boot, not by hibernate. You can see available settings of hibernate here. As soon as you configure the datasource yourself, you will loose the benefit of Spring boot autoconfiguration.
Spring boot hibernate autoconfiguration is managed by this class
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(HibernateProperties.class)
@ConditionalOnSingleCandidate(DataSource.class)
@ImportRuntimeHints(HibernateRuntimeHints.class)
class HibernateJpaConfiguration extends JpaBaseConfiguration {
}

Note the @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate(DataSource.class)
To fix it
Here is how you can adapt your properties with minimum impact
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      show-sql: ${show_sql:true} #shared for both datasource
    ds1:
      properties:
        hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: ${ds1_ddl_auto:update}
    ds2:
      properties:
        hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: ${ds2_ddl_auto:update}


You will have a shared config to print sql statement.
If you still want to keep it different for each datasource, you will have to configure two different instance of JpaVendorAdapter for each datasource (as it is done here)

I think for automatic table creation using the hibernate.ddl-auto parameter, it makes sense for you to try setting it programmatically, for example like this
@Primary
@Bean(name = "ds1EntityManagerFactory")
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ds1EntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder,
        @Qualifier("ds1DataSource") DataSource dataSource,
        @Qualifier("ds1JpaProperties") JpaProperties jpaProperties) {

  Map<String, Object> properties = jpaProperties.getProperties();
  properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
  return entityManagerFactoryBuilder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("a.b.c.d.entity.ds1")
                .persistenceUnit("ds1").properties(properties).build();
}

or at least check that they are read from application.yml
